# Implementation of an HTML word indexer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing an implementation of a word indexer for an HTML file.  I'm running across a problem with the constructor.

In the constructor, I scan through each word in the HTML file and add it to a TreeMap), where the linked list is the collection of indices where the key, the word, appears in the file.  During testing, the linked list never gets bigger than one.  I'm wondering if someone could look at my code and point me in the right direction to where things are getting mixed up.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String temp = scanner.next().toLowerCase();

            if(this.wordMap.containsKey(temp)) {
                LinkedList<Integer> tempList = this.wordMap.get(temp);
                tempList.add(currentIndex);

                wordMap.put(temp, tempList);

                wordCount++;
                currentIndex++;
            }
            else {
                LinkedList<Integer> tempList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                tempList.add(currentIndex);
                wordMap.put(temp, tempList);

                wordCount++;
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you have in the `wordMap` in the end ?

Comment: There is no need for the `wordMap.put(temp, tempList)` inside the if block

Comment: In the if block, I update the linked list with the next index in the section.  I do this by making tempList, setting it equal to the current list of indices of the word, then updating it with the current index, and updating the list with the put method(If the key already exists in the tree, the put method just updates the value).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) in code:

```
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        String temp = scanner.next().toLowerCase();

        LinkedList<Integer> tempList;
        if(this.wordMap.containsKey(temp)) {
            tempList = this.wordMap.get(temp);
        } else {
            tempList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }

        tempList.add(currentIndex);
        wordMap.put(temp, tempList);
        wordCount++;
        currentIndex++;
    }
```

I can't find bug in the code. I suggest to check delimiter in Scanner.